# Laravel vue3 sanctum fortify on api/user unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I'm using laravel sanctum, along with laravel fortify. I'm able to log in, but when I fetch mydomain.test/api/user i'm getting 401 (Unauthorized).

.env

```
APP_URL=http://curriculum.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=curriculim.test,localhost,127.0.0.1
SESSION_DOMAIN=.curriculim.test
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

cors.php

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Here's my login method

```
async login({ dispatch }, payload) {
            try {
                await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');

                await axios.post('/api/login', payload).then((res) => {
                    console.log('successfully logged in')
                    return dispatch('getUser');
                }).catch((err) => {
                    throw err.response
                });


            } catch (e) {
                throw e
            }

        },

        async getUser({commit}) {
            await axios.get('/api/user').then((res) => {
            commit('setUser', res.data);
          }).catch((err) => {

          })
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

- is the cookie in the same domain (e.g. .domain.com)
- Add "withCredentials" to the second axios request
- Maybe CORS error? Check your CORS config

Comment: in my app.js. I have  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;